# Auto generated alphanumeric ID in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Hi everyone I'm new in this site and I want a help from you guys. I'm currently working on my project which i used is VB.net 2010. I need help with my ID that will auto generate.

I want my ID to be like these:
CAT001
CAT002
CAT003
and so on.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and where you're having an issue / error.

Comment: con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(book_id) FROM tbl_book"
        Dim intCount = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        txtCatID.Text = intCount.ToString() + 1
        con.Close()                                                                                           This is the code I've tried and it worked the only problem is only numbers will appear and I dont know how to add a character which I want is CAT001, CAT002 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have some sort of counter for the id number called _idNumber, then you could have something like:

```
Dim idString as String = String.Format("CAT{0}", _idNumber.ToString("D3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub autogenerate_ID()
    Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand

    MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection()
    MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = " server = localhost; user id = root; password=; database = your database "
    Command.Connection = MySqlConnection
    mysqlconnection.Open()

    Dim sqlquery = "select Max(ID) from yourtable "
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim value As String

    value = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        value = "CAT000"
    End If

    value = value.Substring(3)
    Int32.TryParse(value, ID)
    ID = ID + 1
    value = "CAT" + ID.ToString("D3") 
    Txt.Text = value

    command.Dispose()
    mysqlconnection.Close()
    mysqlconnection.Dispose()

End Sub
```